# Any characters after %s in printf, are printed at the start of the line

Tags: c, string, printf

I am reading from a file, knowing that the line is going to be 100 characters or less.

```
char *nodeDetails = malloc(sizeof(char[100])); // Object name or question
char temp[10]; // Question or Object text used to identify line
sscanf(text, "%[Question|Object]: %[^\n]", temp, nodeDetails);
```

I read the line correctly and then later in the program when I try to print it.

```
printf("Is it %s?\n", currentNode->objectName);
```

The output becomes:

```
?t is an alligator
```

Whereas it should be:

```
Is it an alligator?
```

If I don't read the line from the file and just set the objectName manually with a dynamically allocated string. It works fine.
eg.

```
currentNode->objectName = "an alligator";
```

I tired realloc'ing the memory to correct size of

```
sizeof(char[strlen(currentNode->objectName)]);
```

It still does the same thing. So I'm lost.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Debuggers really helps with problems like that, you should inspect `temp` and `nodeDetails` after the `sscanf` and `currentNode->objectName` before the `printf`. also this `sizeof(char[strlen(currentNode->objectName)]);` is incorrect since you need `+1 char` for the NUL termination (and make sure that its actually 0)

Comment: You are a lifesaver @x4rf41! Thanks!! I have realloc'ed it to `length + 1` then set `objectName[newLength - 1] = '\0'` and it solved the problem!

Comment: @x4rf41 do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code has multiple issues.

```
// sscanf(text, "%[Question|Object]: %[^\n]", temp, nodeDetails);
// Check result, drop |, add widths
if (2 != sscanf(text, "%9[QuestionObject]: %99[^\n]", temp, nodeDetails))
  HandleUnexpectedInput();

// This prints wrong because `currentNode->objectName` still has an `\n` in the end of it.
printf("Is it %s?\n", currentNode->objectName);

// As mentioned by x4rf41, add 1.
sizeof(char[strlen(currentNode->objectName) + 1]);
```